# Include own App to share sheet options of other Apps (e.g. Safari) using SwiftUI

Tags: swift

I want to share the URL of the current Safari page with my app from within Safari.

Unfortunately, somehow all SO posts or tutorials deal with how to share URLS, texts, ... **from your own app to other apps** and not the other way around.

Can anyone give me some keywords/WebSite/Documentations/... on how to display my own app in the share sheet options of other apps (e.g. Safari).

Thanks

Comment: Is your app running on iOS or macOS?

Comment: iOS 15+ and I am using Xcode 13

Answer (score 3):

For those who are also just starting with iOS development and are asking the same question:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/app_extension_support/supporting_suggestions_in_your_app_s_share_extension

You have to add a **share extension** to your project. There you can make all the other settings, such as the number and type of objects you can receive (image, text, link, ...) and the view that is displayed when you call your own app.

Comment: Could you elaborate? My understanding is that it's not possible to launch the containing app from a share extension, except via unsupported hacks that App Review may not allow. I'm still looking for the "right way" to do this (on iOS).